# How do you install ClearCase 7.1 on a Unix-based server with no GUI and no internet?

Tags: unix, installation, ibm, silent, clearcase

The challenges set by the ClearCase 7.1 installation process are multiple:

- The installation for Unix has been changed (no more '`./install_server`' script): a unified GUI-based Java tool is used, both for Windows and Unix: the **[Installation Manager (IM)](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r2/index.jsp)**, based on a XML configuration file: the "response file".
- If anything goes wrong, IM will erase *all* the installation, leaving (almost) nothing
- no Gui means [**silent install**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21375571&myns=swgrat&mynp=OCSSSH27&mync=E), but it also means you [cannot **record** easily](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_running%20_im_silently11_rsar.htm) a response file.
- no Internet means, IM will not be able to detect updates and load them for you.

The [**documentation**](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/t_installing_silently_overview.htm) does not cover *completely* this scenario.
My answer below will be there (as a Community Wiki) to record what I have experienced so far regarding this process.

Comment: Other interesting links on the same topic: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21393304 and http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21373364

Comment: Although we are in 2021, there are still SCM admins that need to install ClearCase in a UNIX servers strictly via SSH. Do you know if I can install the ClearCase client v9.0.0 in a Solaris 10 upgrade 6 SPARC server using the way you describe in your answer?

Comment: @Kapoios I think my answer can be used as a starting point, but I would not know if it is enough these days.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Silent Installation of CC7.1 on Unix

(Community Wiki answer: feel free to edit and improve)

#### Prerequisite

- on Unix or Linux, the installation [requires root privileges](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_install.doc/topics/r_user_priv.htm).
- you must have a way to copy the proper installation files on the server (like a sftp access)
- your VOBs must be accessible either locally or through a UFS path

#### Getting the right files

To install the latest CC7.1 (7.1.0.2), you must first install 7.1, then upgrade.
That means you will need:

- a [compatible system](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg21302974).
- a full CC7.1 installation file (through your [Passport Advantage account](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/pao_customers.htm): click on "Customer sign in", then log in, click on "Software download & media access", "I agree", "Download finder", select "IBM Rational ClearCase", then the right platform and language).
  It is recommended to load the setup files with [**Download Director**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/us/ddhelp.html), which supports resume interrupted downloads and perform downloads through firewalls (see here for [usage](http://www6.software.ibm.com/dldirector/doc/DDuse_en.html) and [FAQ](http://www6.software.ibm.com/dldirector/doc/DDfaq_en.html)).
  You will need for:

  - Linux x86: IBM Rational ClearCase Linux x86 V7.1 Multilingual(**C1SQ8ML.zip**, 1.8Go)
  - Solaris (Sun): IBM Rational ClearCase Sun5 V7.1 Multilingual(**C1SQ9ML.zip**, 1.5Go)
  - Solaris (x86): IBM Rational ClearCase Solaris-x86 V7.1 Multilingual(**CZ0R6ML.zip**, 1.1Go)
    Note: if you have Solaris10 on a Sun server, take the Sun5 distro, not the "Solaris-x86" one!
- a response file adapted to your platform: you can find a **[list here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&context=SSSH27&context=SSSTWP&context=SSSTY3&context=SSCSNZN&context=SSCGQ7B&context=SSCGQ7D&context=SSCSP7T&context=SSDV2W&context=SSLLVC&q1=clearcase_response&uid=swg21351501&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en)**.
  Choose `clearcase_response_sun5.xml` or `clearcase_response_linux_x86.xml` to see an example, but one is actually already included in your Cxxx.zip file.
- the latest IM you can get: see this [ftp server](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rationalsdp/v7/im/)
- the last CC Fix Pack you can get: those are *cumulative* patches, so you only need the latest one. See this "[Available iFixes and Fix Packs for ClearCase Family 7.x](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21265307&myns=swgrat&mynp=OCSSSH3S&mynp=OCSSSH32&mynp=OCSSSH27&mync=E)" article.
  For now, this is the [7.1.0.2 fix pack](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/clearcase/7.1.0/7.1.0.2-RATL-RCC/).
- the latest IFix you can get: those are *incremental* patches, so you need to get all of them since the last Fix pack (see same article).
  For now, this is the [7.1.0.2-IFix01](ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/rational/clearcase/7.1.0/7.1.0.2-RATL-RCC-IFIX01/).

Copy those **3 or 4 files (Cxxx.zip, latest IM, latest FixPack, `[`latest IFix`]`)** in any release area you want. Note that you will need around 7Go for the installation files and the complete installation.
**For Solaris10 system, 2 installation will be required**:
- one on the global zone, the release area must be accessible from the ngz (non-global zone)
- one in a ngz, with access to the gz release area (read-only access)

#### Install the main ClearCase Release

- unzip all zip files directly in your release area, **except for IM**: create a sub-directory first (like "`IM1.3.1`") before unzipping it there.
- the main setup zip file Cxxxx.zip will have created a disk1 directory
- copy the response file in disk1 to the release area (the parent directory of disk1)
- [edit your response file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21373364) and modify the following lines:

> If you agree to the license agreement, change the value for the `acceptLicense` key to true.

```
<agent-input acceptLicense='true'>
```

> **3 repository locations** (for CC7.0, latestCC - 7.1.0.2 for instance - and latest IM --1.3 for instance)

```
<repository location='/my/release/area/disk1/InstallerImage_xxx' />
<repository location='/my/release/area/disk1/IM...' /> <!-- ignored: IM1.2 bundle with CC7.0 -->
<repository location='/my/release/area/im13...' /> <!-- latest IM -->
<repository location='/my/release/area/7.1.0.2...' /> <!-- latest CC -->
```

example:

```
<repository location='/usr/scm/ccase_rls/disk1/diskTag.inf' />
<repository location='/usr/scm/ccase_rls/disk1/InstallerImage_solaris' />
<repository location='/usr/scm/ccase_rls/7.1.0.2-RATL-RCC.sun5/repository.config' />
<repository location='/usr/scm/ccase_rls/im13' />
```

> hostname, region and smtp

```
<data key="user.CC_RegSvrHostName,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="mycomputername"/>
<data key="user.CC_RegUNIXRegionName,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="unix_region"/>
<data key="user.CC_RegSMTPHostName,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="mymailserver.mydomain.com"/>
```

> Atria or Flexm settings

```
<data key="user.CC_LICENSE_MANAGER,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="ATRIA"/>
<data key="user.ATRIA_HOST_IS_REMOTE,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="true"/>
<data key="user.ATRIA_REMOTE_HOSTNAME,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="atria_hostname"/>
<data key="user.ATRIA_LOCAL_KEY,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value=""/>
<data key="user.RCL_PortAtHost" value="27000@ss1"/>
```

> For **Linux only**, I would recommend installing *prebuilt* MVFS modules, hence the value "0" to the `user.CC_MVFSModuleRebuild` key. Just make sure you have the source of the kernel at hand with some commands like (**all return values can change depending on *your* context**):

```
$ rpm -q -f /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/Makefile 
  kernel-devel-2.6.18-92.el5
$ rpm -q -f /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build/Module.symvers 
  kernel-devel-2.6.18-92.el5
```

or, simpler:

```
$echo /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build
/lib/modules/2.6.18-128.el5/build
```

To install the sources of the kernel:

```
$ cd /usr/src
$ sudo yum install kernel-devel
$ sudo ln -s kernels/2.6.18-128.el5-x86_64 linux
```

You will see:

```
$l /lib/modules/2.6.18-128.el5
 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root     46 Aug 21 17:01 build -> ../../../usr/src/kernels/2.6.18-128.el5-x86_64/
```

> then (still for Linux only):

```
<data key="user.CC_MVFSModuleRebuild,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="0"/>
<data key="user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="your_kernel_source_directory"/>
```

A typical default value for the kernel source directory, for Linux, if you have made the slink mentioned above:

```
<data key="user.CC_MVFSModuleKernelPath,com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86" value="/usr/src/linux"/>
```

> Select the features you want to install for Rational SDLC, and install also the `com.ibm.cic.agent` offering feature:

```
<install>
        <offering id='com.ibm.rational.clearcase....'
        <offering id='com.ibm.cici.agent'
```

Set the **latest versions** of CC and IM. You will find their id in:

- 7.1.0.2-RATL-RCC.linux_x86/repository.config: UPDATES_com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86~**7.1.2.0000-7-1-0-02-00-2009BD090617**= com.ibm.rational.clearcase.linux_x86~7.1.0.00-7-1-081110~7.1
- im13/configuration/config.ini: im.internal.version=**1.3.1000.20090618_1714**
- To run the installation, from your release area

> Command:

```
 sudo ./im13/install --launcher.ini ./im13/silent-install.ini -silent -ShowVerboseProgress -input ./clearcase_response.xml > & install_7.1.0.0.log
```

Principles:

- if no CC is installed, it will install 7.0, then upgrade 7.1.0.2 **in one step**.
- do not use the IM bundled with CC (disk1/InstallerImage_xxx): it is a 1.2 one, too low to install latest CC. Use directly the latest IM.
- always redirect `stdout` and `stderr` in a custom ad-hoc log file
- if any error message (even a [problem during one '`mount vob`'](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21382693)), there would be a *complete* rollback. If so, your ad-hoc log file is useful, but you can also find the IM log files at

> IM log files:

```
/var/ibm/InstallationManager/logs/native
```

#### Un-installation

In case of problem or uncompleted installation, you can always un-install the product but:

- it removes *everything*
- save /var/adm/atria first (your registry settings)
- just replace the  element by an `<uninstall modify='false'>` element
- the command remains the same
- If you un-install an offerring version 7.1.0.2, it un-installs *all* ClearCase, not just the patch put on 7.1.0.0

Comment: Note: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21579102&myns=swgrat&mynp=OCSSSH27&mync=R is the revised procedure for ClearCase 7.1.2 "Silent install of ClearCase on Linux from share without IM installed locally by example"

Answer (score 2):

## TroubleShooting: Gdk-CRITICAL error

The process stops immediately with several errors beginning with `Gdk-CRITICAL error`

### Symptom

If the process fails with the following set of error messages:

```
(install:22364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: file gdkwindow-x11.c: line 1279: assertion `GDK_IS_WINDOW (window)' failed
(install:22364): Gtk-WARNING **: Screen for GtkWindow not set; you must always set
a screen for a GtkWindow before using the window
(install:22364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: file gdkwindow-x11.c: line 1299: assertion `window != NULL' failed
(install:22364): Gdk-CRITICAL **: file gdkwindow-x11.c: line 1299: assertion `window != NULL' failed
(install:22364): Gtk-CRITICAL **: file gtkstyle.c: line 910: assertion `GTK_IS_STYLE (style)' failed
(install:22364): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: file gobject.c: line 1579: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
...
```

### Cause

This is "normal" as it validates the need for a silent install, and not a GUI-based one: you do not have the graphical environment needed to launch that GUI.
However the cause is simple: one of the parameter is incorect.

For example, using:

```
--launcher.ini ./disk1/InstallerImage_solaris/silent_install.ini
```

instead of:

```
--launcher.ini ./disk1/InstallerImage_solaris/silent-install.ini
```

(note the '`_`' instead of '`-`' in the `silent-install.ini` filename)

### Workaround/resolution

Fix the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

## TroubleShooting: Containing directory could not be set for directory shortcut"IBM Installation Manager"

The process stops and cleanup the install because of a "directory shortcut" not set

### Symptom

```
Cleaning up saved files.  (100% of < 1 MB at 71 KB/sec; 0 seconds remain)
Cleaning up saved files.
Error during "install" phase:
  Containing directory could not be set for directory shortcut"IBM Installation Manager".
Install:
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
...
```

### Cause

This [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21308289) details the cause:

`/usr/share/desktop-directories` is not writable.

That happens especially on a **Solaris installation in a NGZ (Non-Global-Zone), where `/usr/share` is common with the Global Zone, but is not writable from a NGZ**.

### Workaround/resolution

For `ksh` session

```
sudo export XDG_DATA_HOME=/var/IBM/desktop-directories
```

For `tcsh` session

```
sudo setenv XDG_DATA_HOME /var/IBM/desktop-directories
```

That plus the usual `sudo ./install --launcher ...` will make the installation process create the `desktop-directories` and its shortcuts in a *writable* directory.

Note: you can make `/var/IBM/desktop-directories` link to any non-standard path as well (like `/export/IBM/desktop-directories`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the information you are looking for in the following technotes.

Since I can only post one URL here, I've listed the other technote numbers below.
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21390817

If you replace the last 7 digits of the above URL with any of the following technote numbers, you can view the other five:

1393769
1393735
1393304
1390818
1393738

I hope this helps;-)

Comment: @Denise Thank you for those links. The relevant ones are already mentioned as comment on my question above since yesterday.