# Can I install ClearCase 7.1 With non-root

Tags: clearcase

I would like to install clearcase 7.1 on AIX. but i'm not system admin of this server i can get root password for install only. i worry if after install i cannot configure or manage Clearcase by another user. so i would like to install by non-root user.

Answer (score 2):

I have some experience with ClearCase on Solaris, Linux and Windows hosts.

On UNIX, the ClearCase installation needs to install kernel modules for MVFS file system support, and init scripts for startup at boot among other things.

ClearCase itself needs to start as root to load the drivers, and mount VOB file systems etc.

I can not see an easy way to get around this. You might be able to install and run the eclipse-based ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC) without root access, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, on Unix or Linux, the [installation of ClearCase requires root privileges](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc%5Fms%5Finstall.doc/topics/r%5Fuser%5Fpriv.htm).

See this [SO answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/49786/how-do-you-install-clearcase-7-1-on-a-unix-based-server-with-no-gui-and-no-intern) for an example of detailed installation (with a lot of links to IBM documentation).

Generally, for this kind of administration operations, you should be able to have a "sudo root" right in order for you to install then manage ClearCase, while having every command you type recorded.

That would be:

- sudo root for all commands onlt for installation
- sudo root for a handful of ClearCase commands for administration privileges.