# How do you install ClearCase 7.0 on a Unix-based server with no GUI and no internet?

Tags: linux, clearcase

How do you install ClearCase 7.0 on a Linux VM running on RedHAt version 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

You follow the [Installation Manager command-line arguments](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.silentinstall12.doc/topics/r_silent_inst_cmd_arg.html) in order to perform a silent installation, based on a response file you will have adequately modified.

See **[Examples of response file](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.silentinstall12.doc/topics/c_sample_response_files.html)** to see what such a file look like.

The general principle is described here: [Installing, updating, and scripting installations for IBM Installation Manager](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/install/v1r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.im.articles.doc/topics/SCRIPTING_IM.htm) and is implemented in this [SF answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/49786/how-do-you-install-clearcase-7-1-on-a-unix-based-server-with-no-gui-and-no-intern/49787#49787).